# react native export default multi component

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native, How to export default two components,

I have a class which use withNavigation and redux connect, and I have to export them as default to work properly.

```js
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
.
.
.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClassName);

export default withNavigation(ClassName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use compose from 'redux'

```
import {compose} from 'redux'
...
export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
   withNavigation
)(ClassName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap your component by all higher-order functions to use all of them:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withNavigation(ClassName));
```